# Turning off the screen programmatically for a system app

Tags: android, screen

I have an activity in a system app. I want to click on a button and it turns off the screen. How do i do it?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                turnOffScreen()
            }
        });

private void turnOffScreen(){
    //To implement
}
```

I saw many questions about it but it didn't give me the answer and it was not for system apps.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking for, turn off as in lock the device or turn off as in `brightness=0`?

Comment: Turn off as when you short press once the power button